# ansible list content based on condition

Tags: ansible

I would like to set list content in Ansible vars/defaults based on condition, something like:

```
my_list:
{% if condition %}
- item 1
- item 2
{% else %}
- item3
- item4
{% endif %}
```

It there a way to do that using ansible/jinja syntax? Since I want this in vars/defaults, using `set_fact` + `when` would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It there a way to do that using ansible/jinja syntax?

Yes, lots, however:

> Since I want this in vars/defaults

makes your question invalid, since jinja2 are not evaluated inside vars_files (which includes `defaults/*.yml`), they are only evaluated upon use

But, the answer to your question is *mostly*:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      my_list is {{ ["item 1", "item 2"] if condition else ["item 3", "item 4"] }}
```

or some folks prefer the [`ternary` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#defining-different-values-for-true-false-null-ternary):

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      my_list is {{ condition | ternary(["item 1", "item 2"], ["item 3", "item 4"]) }}
```

and, if those two list alternates are huge, you can always declare the sub-lists in `defaults/` and just choose between them based on `condition`:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: >-
      my_list is {{ sub_list_1 if condition else sub_list_2 }}
  vars:
    sub_list_1:
    - item 1
    - item 2
    sub_list_2:
    - item 3
    - item 4
```

Comment: Thanks!

But you are not right about jinja in var_files. I've used jinja there(but for simple strings only) for a long time.

Right now this works for me in group_vars:

```
ntp_servers_aws_internal:
  - 169.254.169.123 iburst minpoll 4 maxpoll 4

ntp_servers: "{{ ntp_servers_aws_internal if aws_host | default(False)) else [] }}"
```

And I checked that it works in `role/defaults` also.

Comment: Stackoverflow rejects syntax in comments, so here: https://gist.github.com/selivan/41dd9527a7d3e9889ad90d495f416e9f

Comment: I appreciate that you believe that's true, but I specifically said _on use_ and I said that on purpose; if your hypothesis were true and it evaluated jinja in the vars files, then `echo 'kaboom: "{{ NOT_DEFINED_ON_NOES }}"' > group_vars/all.yml` would explode on any playbook

Comment: I didn't read carefully, you are right and it is evaluated on use.  But that does not make much difference in usage.